# Kafka Streams: How to transform message before publishing to different topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Messages on Topic A are read using Kafka Streams. Based on some validation, the message is published to either Topic B or Topic C. This was easily achieved using Kafka Streams' [branch](https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#branch-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Predicate...-) method

```
KStreamBuilder kStreamBuilder = new KStreamBuilder();
KStream<String, String> kStream = kStreamBuilder.stream(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String(), topicA.split(","));

KStream<String, String>[] splitStreams = kStream.branch(
    (key, value) -> process(value), //Process method is expensive
    (key, value) -> true
);

splitStreams[0].to(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String(), topicB);
splitStreams[1].to(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String(), topicC);
```

Problem: Based on whether the message passes or fails validation, it is to be edited/appended before publishing it to either Topic B or Topic C. How do
I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

for transforming messages you could use the following `KStream` methods:

- `map` (for updating message based by key & value)
- `mapValues` (for updating message based by value)
- `selectKey` (for updating key based by key & value)

example:

```
splitStreams[0].mapValues(value -> transformValueForTopicB(value))
        .to(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String(), topicB);
splitStreams[1].map((key, value) -> transformValueForTopicC(key, value))
        .to(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String(), topicC);
```

also as I see from your `process` method name inside `branch` method, potentially you try to process value, but you only need to provide `Predicate` (that returns `true` or `false`) without any processing.

Comment: I want to return ProcessResult object from my process method. It will have a boolean indicating true or false. I want to transform stream1 and stream2 based on the ProcessResult object. I do not want to run my process(value) method twice as it is expensive. How can i achieve that?

Comment: ok, so you could invoke  `mapValues` with `process` logic before `.branch()` which will transform your value into `ProcessResult ` object. for example, `ProcessResult ` could have fields: yourRequiredValue and one boolean field. in `branch` method you could check only this boolean field, and after that you need one more `mapValues` that transform `ProcessResult ` object into string

Comment: `KStream<String, ProcessResult>[] splitStreams = kStream.mapValues(value -> process(value))
                .branch((key, value) -> value.isRelateToTopicB, (key, value) -> true);
        splitStreams[0].mapValues(value -> value.getProcessedValue()).to(...);`